# SDO API: how to make XSDHelper.INSTANCE to define XSD schemas with <include> correctly?

Tags: java, xml, xsd, websphere, sdo

I'm facing a following problem.
We're using Service Data Objects since our target runtime is IBM WebSphere which supposes to be native for this API. The stack that we're using is Java EE, Eclipse Oxygen as the main IDE, SDO reference implementation according to SDO 2.1.0 specification, IBM WebSphere 9 and JRE8.

According to SDO javadoc there are a `define(java.io.InputStream xsdInputStream, java.lang.String schemaLocation)` method under `XSDHelper` class which loads a desired XSD schema into the WAS runtime. Once the schema is being loaded its type becomes available for other operations, including `DataObject` creation..
The way I define schemas looks like the following:

```
InputStream is = new BOStorage().getInputStreamXSD("/test.xsd"); 
XSDHelper.INSTANCE.define(is, null);
```

The `define()` method invokes from the EJB constructor.
`test.xsd` is located under the **src** folder of my eclipse project.

```
src
| test.xsd
| test1.xsd
|
|___ejb.package.name
```

Now a little bit about the test.xsd itself. It references to another XSDs of the same `targetNamespace` using `<include>` tag:

**test.xsd snippet:**

```
...
<xsd:schema
    targetNamespace="http://ejb/package/name"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:bons0="http://ejb/package/name">
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="test1.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <xsd:include schemaLocation="test2.xsd"></xsd:include>
    <xsd:complexType name="TestSDO">
...
<xsd:element minOccurs="0" name="RefObject"
                type="bons0:RefObject">
            </xsd:element>
...
```

`test1.xsd` contains a `complexType` named `RefObject`, which is referenced in `test.xsd`.

**test1.xsd snippet:**

```
...
<xsd:complexType name="RefObject">

          <xsd:simpleContent>
            <xsd:extension base="xsd:string">
                <xsd:attribute name="type"/>
            </xsd:extension>
        </xsd:simpleContent>

  </xsd:complexType>
...
```

As official SDO Java spec for the version 2.1.0 says:

> **9.7 XSD Mapping Details**
>
> ...
>
> 4. All `<group>` references, `<attributeGroup>` references, `<include>`s, and  `<import>`s are fully expanded to the equivalent XSD as if these
>      declarations were not present.
>
> ...

For my vision that means, that in my case, SDO implementation should:

1. Load test.xsd;
2. Figures out, that it references to the `test1.xsd` in its `<include>` section;
3. As the `test1.xsd` located at the same `src` folder, as the `test.xsd` is, my expectations is that it would be implicitly loaded in WebSphere runtime environment.

But I'm experiencing an error while trying to create a DataObject of `RefObject` type:

> CWSDO0001E: Cannot create a data object of the type
>   {http://ejb/package/name}RefObject
>   because the type cannot be found

The conclusions I can make is that SDO API isn't designed to work that way or my XSD's or any aren't suitable or contain some mistakes.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

**UPDATE:**
It works just as expected in case of using the "global" XSD, which includes all references inline. Everything I've mentioned before is running from stateless EJB bean.

A sample code leading to the error:

```
        @Stateless(mappedName = "TestSDO")
        @Remote(TestSDORemote.class)
        @Local(TestSDOLocal.class)

        public class TestSDO implements TestSDORemote, TestSDOLocal{
            ...


        // default EJB constructor

     public TestSDO() {
           String textInfo = "";

            try {
                defineSDOTypes();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.log(Level.WARNING, "Could not define SDO types");
            }
        }
             ...
      private void defineSDOTypes() {
            HelperContext hc =   
            SDO.getHelperContextFactory().createHelperContext("ScopeManagerTestID", 
            null);
            XSDHelper xsdHelper = hc.getXSDHelper();
            try (InputStream is = new BOStorage().getInputStreamXSD("/test.xsd")) {          
                 xsdHelper.define(is, null);    
            } catch (IOException e) { 
              LOGGER.logp(Level.WARNING, CLASS_NAME, METHOD_NAME, "Unable to load the 
              schema: " + 
              "test.xsd" + ": " + e.getMessage());      
               e.printStackTrace();     
            }
             ...
      // creates the target Data Object (here comes the error)
      private void createBO(){
            DataObject dob = DataFactory.INSTANCE.create("http://ejb/package/name", 
            "RefObject");
        }
             ...
```

Comment: The namespace URI `http://http://ejb/package/name` in the error message looks odd; maybe an instance of [this Tuscany bug](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/TUSCANY-2080)?

Comment: Btw. SDO/SCA is IMHO a fantastic API, but has been long superseded by JEE APIs (JAXB/JAX-WS etc.) as Java implementation for a component within SCA (the Apache Tuscany SCA/SDO reference implementation on which WebSphere's is based [has been retired](http://tuscany.apache.org/))

Comment: @imhotap , i'm sorry, it was my fault since I've slightly edited the error message. The actual URI from the log seems to be correct.
As for me SDO is a nice API, but the specs sometimes are not transparent and as you've mentioned, it has been retired and not widely used.

Comment: Since you already have been warned this is an older API... it might help you to realize that WebSphere's SDO type registry is set up analogous to the classloader hierarchy, allowing applications to define types in their own scopes, in isolation from other applications.    It could be the case that you are defining the type in one scope, but accessing it from another.     Maybe include the Java code leading up to the error when you "create a DataObject.."    Also, is this an SCA application or not?

Comment: I realized my last update suggests another question:  "does it work if you copy the included defs inline into the including XSD?"   (If it's a scoping issue you'd think you'd hit the same problem either way).

Comment: @Scott Kurz it works perfectly if i merging all referenced XSD together. Please see updated question. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [Tuscany SDO repo](https://github.com/apache/tuscany-sdo) it seems you want to do something like:

```
    URL url = getClass().getResource("/test.xsd");
    InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
    xsdHelper.define(inputStream, url.toString());
    inputStream.close();
```

That is, instead of doing `xsdHelper.define(is, null)`, I think you need to pass in a value for the second parm: **schemaLocation** as the [javadoc](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/api/2.1/commonj/sdo/helper/XSDHelper.html#define(java.io.Reader,%20java.lang.String)) suggests:

> schemaLocation - the URI of the location of the schema, used for processing relative imports and includes. May be null if not used.